# get next and previous inputs on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the value of the previous and next input by click on  `a` element styling as a button...
Example code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text">
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="li-inline">
        <a class="btn" href="#">
            <i class=""></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try with `next()` and `prev()` jquery methods but have not achieved the expected results.

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).next(":input");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to reach the parent `ul` using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then go to next or previous `ul` using [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) respectively and find input in the descendants using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/mzEKQ/)**

```
$("a").click(function() {
     $(this).closest('ul').prev('ul').find(":input");
     $(this).closest('ul').next('ul').find(":input");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var $a = $(this);
    var prevInputValue = $a.closest('ul').prev().find('input').val();
    var nextInputValue = $a.closest('ul').next().find('input').val();
});
```

In your original code, `next()` doesn't work because the `input` elements are not siblings of the `a`. You need to traverse the DOM to find the relevant `ul` which contains them.

Comment: @user1852540 no problem. Don't forget to click the green ticknext to the answer which helped you best.

Comment: all answers are valid and displayed very similar. I marked as valid  the first because work fine and was the first response, anyway, thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$("a").click(function() {

var previous =   $($(this).closest('ul').prev('ul').find.(":input").get(0)).val();

var next=   $($(this).closest('ul').next('ul').find.(":input").get(0)).val();
});
```

Thanks